# Customize label in stacked column chart extjs

Tags: extjs, calculated-columns, stacked

[image: i make columns chart like this but]

i make columns chart like this but this make mismatch when data are low, that time i need to display it ouside ot the chart
like
[image]

is this possible to make outside label in extjs stacked columns chart..

code is here

```
ar store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'metric one', 'data1': 4, 'data2': 12, 'data3': 14, 'data4': 8, 'data5': 13 },
        { 'name': 'metric two', 'data1': 7, 'data2': 8, 'data3': 16, 'data4': 10, 'data5': 3 },
        { 'name': 'metric three', 'data1': 5, 'data2': 2, 'data3': 14, 'data4': 12, 'data5': 7 },
        { 'name': 'metric four', 'data1': 2, 'data2': 14, 'data3': 6, 'data4': 1, 'data5': 4},
        { 'name': 'metric five', 'data1': 7, 'data2': 4, 'data3':4, 'data4': 13, 'data5': 4 }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    animate: true,
    store: store,
    axes: [
        {
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
            label: {
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
            },
            title: 'Sample Values',
            grid: true,
            minimum: 0
        },
        {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['name'],
            title: 'Sample Metrics'
        }
    ],
    series: [
        {
            type: 'column',
            axis: 'left',
            highlight: true,

            label: {
                display: 'middle',
                'text-anchor': 'middle',
                field: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
                orientation: 'horizontal',
                contrast: true,
                color: '#333'
                field: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],


            },
stacked: true,
            xField: 'name',
            yField: ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm Not sure about right side but, using this code, your data will show on chart, and if chart value are high, then data will go under chart, and also show Y-axis and X-axis data on mouse Hover.

```
    |-----|                                                                  
    |  89 |                  50                                               
    |     |      20       |-----|                                              
    |     |    |-----|    |     |                                             
    |     |    |     |    |     |                                               
    |     |    |     |    |     |                                             
    |     |    |     |    |     |
```

---

**My Code** (I use extjs 4.0 chart in extjs 3.4, so I need "ext-all-sandbox.js")

```
Ext4.create('Ext4.chart.Chart',{
 renderTo: 'divAverageChart2',
 width: 450,
 height: 380,
 style: 'background:#fff',
 animate: true,
 store: AverageChart2Store, 
    items: [{
      type  : 'text',
      cls:'bold',
     // text  : 'Performance Matrix of Student Mayur Macwan Grade : 5th',
      font  : '14px Calibri',
      width : 100,
      height: 30,
      x : 80, //the sprite x position
      y : 370  //the sprite y position
   }],
    legend: {
         position: 'bottom',
         labelFont: 'tahoma'
    },
 axes: [{
    type: 'Numeric',
    position: 'left',
    minimum: 0,                                 
    fields: ['data1'],      
    label: {
       renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0')
    }
},{
    type: 'Category',
    position: 'bottom',                 
    fields: ['name']                
}],
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    axis: 'left',
    showInLegend: false,
    xField: 'name',             
    yField: ['data1'],
    title: ['Top 5 Products'],  
    label: {
         display: 'outside',
         'text-anchor': 'middle',
         field: ['data1','data2','data3','data4'],
         renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0'),
         orientation: 'horizontal',
         color: '#333'
    },               
    tips: {
      trackMouse: true,
      width: 140,
      height: 28,
      renderer: function(storeItem, item) {                     
        this.setTitle(item.value);
      }
    }
}],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(view){
            Ext.each(view.legend.items, function(item) {
                item.un("mousedown", item.events.mousedown.listeners[0].fn);
            })
        }
    }
});
```

**Other Way** (This works for me)

```
    <text id="ext-sprite-1222" style="font: 11px Helvetica,sans-serif;" zIndex="0" font="11px Helvetica, sans-serif" fill="#333" text-anchor="middle" text="37" x="110.206" y="228" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" hidden="false">
<tspan x="171.206" dy="3.5">37</tspan>
</text>
```

Here you have to change X-axis and Y-axis value as per your need.

change X-axis and dy value in below code as per your need code.

```
<tspan x="171.206" dy="3.5">37</tspan>
```

Comment: this is very good example, really,good one. but i didn't get "other way". how to use it?

Comment: @jeegnesh in that, you have to find id "ext-sprite" in related extjs' js files.
and changes values as per your need, in my case, I use "ext-all-sandbox.js" so i have to find "ext-sprite" and change values, but some technical logic are needed. thanks.

Comment: @jeegnesh you can also use "ext-all-sandbox.js" file in your code, but it is in .min version, so you bit conflict during editing, or send me your whole code, so can change it and test in my way or use jsfiddle for show your working output